# Gradle legacy multi module build: working around bad choices

Tags: java, gradle

I have a legacy WebApp project composed of many legacy modules and a few new modules. I'm working on migrating the existing project to a Gradle based build *without* changing the folder structure (at least for now).

The module structure is very flat as in the following:

```
project-root
|-- module1
|-- module2
|-- module3
|-- module4
|-- newModule (newly added!)
|   |-- sub1
|   |-- sub2
```

Now let's say `module1` and `module2` need to be deployed in a WAR file, say `war1.war`, `module3` and `module4` in a different WAR file, say `war2.war` and finally `newModule:sub1` and `newModule:sub2` will be deployed as two standalone applications.

Now I'm debating about how to create these artifacts. Should I have a separate additional war module for each artifact, i.e., one for `war1` and the other for `war2`? Or should I have two tasks in the root project? If so, how can I use the war plugin to produce many different artifacts? Or should I just choose a module to be the host for the two artifacts, i.e., have `module1` build `war1` and `module3` build `war2` or something like that? Or finally should I reorganize the project (which I'm trying to avoid to do) to something like this:

```
project-root
|-- war1
|   |-- module1
|   |-- module2
|-- war2
|   |-- module3
|   |-- module4
|-- newModule
|   |-- sub1
|   |-- sub2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you this:

```
project-root
|-- module1 - apply plugin: 'jar'
|-- module2 - apply plugin: 'jar'
|-- module3 - apply plugin: 'jar'
|-- module4 - apply plugin: 'jar'
|-- newModule (newly added!)
|   |-- sub1
|   |-- sub2
|-- war1  - apply plugin: 'war'
|   dependencies {
|     compile project(':module1')
|     compile project(':module2')
|   }
|-- war2  - apply plugin: 'war'
|   dependencies {
|     compile project(':module3')
|     compile project(':module4')
|   }
```

war1 and war2 are mere containers for the build.gradle with the settings I suggest you.  How do you see it?

Comment: This is the solution I also came up with by thinking about it for a while. I think it'll work.

Comment: It will work, and is a good and flexible solution. Making existing projects the hosts is also fine, and is a natural solution if for each War, one project is clearly tied to that War (e.g. contains all JSPs), without potential of reuse in a different context. Reorganizing directory structure doesn't provide any advantages. For example, even with a flat structure, Gradle is smart enough to rebuild dependent projects automatically as necessary. In summary, the legacy structure doesn't seem bad at all.